# Determine whether two arrays are equal

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

You are given two arrays to find out if they are equal?

One way to solve it is to use a hash table. How can I accomplish this using a hash table?

Comment: Why can't you just compare them element-by-element?  Isn't that easier, faster, and more memory-efficient?

Comment: If you can't use a normal container, why not `std::equal`?

Comment: What's your definition of "equal" for two arrays? That's not a snarky comment; your question implies "have the same elements in any order", but that's not the obvious meaning for an array.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::array`:

```
std::array<int, 3> var = {{ 1, 2, 3 }},
                   bar = {{ 4, 5, 6 }};
                   baz = {{ 1, 2, 3 }};

std::cout << std::boolalpha << (var == baz)  // true
                            << (bar == baz); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do it in O(n).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

bool equal( const vector<int> &v1, const vector<int> &v2 )
{
    if ( v1.size() != v2.size() )
        return false;

    unordered_map <int,int> map1, map2;

    for ( auto it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it )
        map1[*it]++;

    for ( auto it = v2.begin(); it != v2.end(); ++it )
        map2[*it]++;

    if ( map1 != map2 )
        return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    // create first array
    vector<int> v1(10);
    generate_n(v1.begin(), v1.size(), rand);

    // create second array
    vector<int> v2 (v1);
    std::random_shuffle(v2.begin(),v2.end());

    // print arrays
    copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\t")); cout << endl;
    copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\t")); cout << endl;

    cout << (equal(v1,v2) ? "equal" : "not equal") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Due to the usage of unordered maps this compares indeed all the elements no matter what order they are in. Example: {1,2,3,4,5} = {5,4,3,2,1} != {1,2,9999,4,5}

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this C++, you can directly use the overloaded `operator ==` on `std::array`.

Comment: @MooingDuck yeah, missed the last part with `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just algorithmical, and you want to use something like a hash table follow these steps:

1. Create a new table with size equal to a number of possible characters/numbers to be inside of the arrays you compare (for example, if your arrays to compare have ASCII chars you need to create a tab sized 255).
2. Fill your new table with zeros (0).
3. Go through the first table (loop for) and increment a field of your hash table which index is equal to tested char:`for (int i=0; i<tab1.size; i++) hashtab[tab1[i]]++;`
4. Go through the second table (loop for) and decrement a field of your hash table, which index is equal to tested char.`for (int i=0; i<tab2.size; i++) hashtab[tab2[i]]--;`
5. Finally go through your hash table (loop for). If Any of its fields is different from 0, the tables do not contain the same elements. Else, tables do contain same elements.

If you reach the end of the table without returning false, then it was all zeros.
This can be used for example to see if two words are made of the same letters (EXACTLY same letters, same number of each of them).